# Java code after Selenium Click event is not working

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a page using selenium with Java, The code seems to be working fine until a point but after that nothing works.

Please find the code below:

```
          try {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id='itm_0'] tbody tr td a[class='LVL0']"));
            element1.click();

            element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"varTableIdResult\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
            element1.click();

            element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("expand"));
            element1.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            System.out.println("Initiated successfully");

            String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println("the window handle name is::"+parentWindow);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"DetailsForm\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/img")).click();

            //Code works till this point, but next steps are not executed

            driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
            System.out.println("Before PDF Save");  
            PDFSave ();
            System.out.println("Before PDF Save");
        }


public void PDFSave() throws InterruptedException {
        // -- AutoIT Code needed for PDF Save
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("C:\\LogFiles\\PDFSave.exe");
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Console Output:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.9.0.0

launching IE Browser
Initiated successfully
the window handle name is::c0a1854c-4ef4-4c29-9b7d-6bf84a539053
```

- What I see is that when the DetailsForm image is clicked, a new Popup window is opened but it seems like the click event is still waiting for the process to get completed.

Any suggestion on how this problem can be fixed ?
How do I bring back the control to java code ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'DetailsForm\']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/img")).click();   change according to it and try .make sure there should not be two times quotations in xpath

Comment: Does the popup window ever finish loading? `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);` isn't going to do anything because you are switching context to the current window handle. You need to loop through the window handles collection and switch to the window handle that *isn't* the current window handle. If you do some googling, you'll find examples of this.

Comment: @RamanaMuttana That's not the issue. If it was, it would have failed a few lines above and would have thrown an error. What he has is fine. In your case, you are escaping the single quotes `'` that don't need to be escaped. You can do `By.xpath("//*[@id='DetailsForm']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/img"` and I think it's a lot more readable.

Comment: @RamanaMuttana Thanks for your advice, I did change the xpath value as suggested but the result remains the same. The actual problem lies in the code after that, if you notice the Console output, even the Sysout commands after the "DetailsForm" line is not being executed.

Comment: @JeffC Yes, The Popup window does finish loading, but the click even after that which is via AutoIT does not work (It does work when the AutoIT code is triggered as a standalone program). If you notice the Console output, even the Sysout commands after the "DetailsForm" line is not being executed.

Comment: What I have come to understand is that this is an existing issue with selenium Click event. There is an error being thrown by the web page but that's not recorded or displayed in the console. So in short, a fix for this problem is not yet available !